Getting error maximum call stack size exceeded when Exporting Data from Firebase Firestore to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script
I want to export data from firestore to googl sheets using Google Apps Script, I followed along this tutorial.
what I did
I added a library by getting script ID from project settings and named the identifier "FirestoreApp" then I added a service which is google sheets api after that I add the code and tried to excute it
this is the code I used
function getFirestore(){

  var email = "";
  var key = "";
  var projectId = "";

  return FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email,key,projectId);
}

function myFunction() {
  //1. Initialize variables
  let firestore  = getFirestore();
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activeSheet.getActiveSheet();

  //2. Read documents from collection in Array
  let allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("Doctors");

//3. Iterate through the array items
for(var i = 0; i < allDocuments.length; i++){

  //A. initialize Array to be printed to google sheet
  var myArray = [];

// B. access columns
  var name = allDocuments[i].fields["name"];
  myArray.push(name.stringValue);

var major = allDocuments[i].fields["major"];
  myArray.push(major.stringValue);

//C.write array as rows in google sheets
  sheet.appendRow(myArray);

}
}

I also enabled google sheets API in google cloud
the problem is that I keep getting this error while running the code
Error   
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1
getFirestore    @ Code.gs:1


Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question doesn't include enough details. How are you executing the code?

I'm using https://script.google.com to export the data from firebase to google sheets, can you please check the link of the tutorial i followed above ..

While a link to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. This means that you should add all the relevant details directly into the question body. This is important because, watching the video, we will not know if you did all that the video creator did and if both of you have exactly the same setup / enviroment.
